# Can I import libsyntax in my code?

Tags: rust

I want to import the rust lexer in my code

```
use syntax;

fn main() { () }
```

but above code fails to compile

```
error: failed to resolve imports
testparse.rs:1:4: 1:11 error: unresolved import
testparse.rs:1 use syntax;
                   ^~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Can I use libsyntax from user code? If I can, how can I import it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the library:

```
extern mod syntax;
```